# How do I turn on Autosave in Office 365 applications?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, office365, autosave

For all my Powerpoint presentations and Excel workbooks (but not Word documents) on the Windows 10 version of Office 365, I have a little badge "AutoSave Off" in the corner.

[image: AutoSave Off]

This occurs is there whether I just created a new file or am working on a previously saved one.

I assume this means that the files aren't autosaving. If that's accurate how do I turn autosave on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Autosave icon in the Office 365 refers only to saving to shared/internet locations, such as OneDrive.  If you save locally, it can still do automatic recovery saves, but it's not the same thing as this function.

Mousing over the button shows the following tool tip:
[image]

Going to **File** -> **Options** -> **Save** still has the following options:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is related to online/cloud-stored files. Microsoft states;

> AutoSave is enabled when a file is stored on OneDrive, OneDrive for
>   Business, or SharePoint Online. It automatically saves your changes to
>   the cloud as you are working. And, if other people are working on the
>   same file, AutoSave lets them see your changes in a matter of seconds.

Source - [What is AutoSave?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-AutoSave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5)